# Using dplyr's do to perform bootstrap replications

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm interested in using dplyr to construct bootstrap replications (repeated analyses where the data is first sampled with replacement each time). Hadley Wickham [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/269) provides some code for repeating bootstrapped analyses in an efficient way:

```
bootstrap <- function(df, m) {
  n <- nrow(df)

  attr(df, "indices") <- replicate(m, sample(n, replace = TRUE), 
    simplify = FALSE)
  attr(df, "drop") <- TRUE
  attr(df, "group_sizes") <- rep(n, m)
  attr(df, "biggest_group_size") <- n
  attr(df, "labels") <- data.frame(replicate = 1:m)
  attr(df, "vars") <- list(quote(boot)) # list(substitute(bootstrap(m)))
  class(df) <- c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")

  df
}

library(dplyr)
mboot <- bootstrap(mtcars, 10)

# Works
mboot %.% summarise(mean(cyl))
```

While this function works well for `summarise`, it doesn't work for `do` when `do` contains a data.frame. (Imagine for now that the data.frame contains something useful such as the results of the analysis we wish to bootstrap).

```
bootstrap(mtcars, 3) %>% do(data.frame(x=1:2))
# Error: index out of bounds
```

with the traceback

```
11: stop(list(message = "index out of bounds", call = NULL, cppstack = NULL))
10: .Call("dplyr_grouped_df_impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", data, symbols, 
        drop)
9: grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop)
8: grouped_df(cbind_list(labels, out), groups)
7: label_output_dataframe(labels, out, groups(.data))
6: do.grouped_df(`bootstrap(mtcars, 3)`, data.frame(x = 1:2))
5: do(`bootstrap(mtcars, 3)`, data.frame(x = 1:2))
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(e, env)
2: withVisible(eval(e, env))
1: bootstrap(mtcars, 3) %>% do(data.frame(x = 1:2))
```

I was able to work around this by performing two `do` steps and a group by:

```
bootstrap(mtcars, 10) %>% do(d=data.frame(x=1:2)) %>% group_by(replicate) %>% do(.$d[[1]])
```

but this seems to require a lot of extra, and somewhat clumsy, steps (and also gets a warning, `Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature`). I'm also aware that I could replicate the data into ten replications first with something like

```
data.frame(boot=1:10) %>% group_by(boot) %>% do(sample_n(mtcars, nrow(mtcars), replace=TRUE))
```

but if the data or the number of bootstrap replicates is large this is extremely inefficient in memory.

Is there a way, perhaps by altering the `bootstrap` setup function, that I can perform these replicates with `bootstrap(mtcars, 3) %>% do(data.frame(x = 1:2))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is a small bug in the `bootstrap` function. The `vars` attribute should match the column name in the `data.frame` in the `labels` attribute. But in the function, the `vars` attribute is called `"boot"`, and the column name is `replicate`. So, if you make this minor change:

```
bootstrap <- function(df, m) {
  n <- nrow(df)

  attr(df, "indices") <- replicate(m, sample(n, replace = TRUE), 
                                   simplify = FALSE)
  attr(df, "drop") <- TRUE
  attr(df, "group_sizes") <- rep(n, m)
  attr(df, "biggest_group_size") <- n
  attr(df, "labels") <- data.frame(replicate = 1:m)
  attr(df, "vars") <- list(quote(replicate)) # Change
#  attr(df, "vars") <- list(quote(boot)) # list(substitute(bootstrap(m)))
  class(df) <- c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")

  df
}
```

Then it works as expected:

```
bootstrap(mtcars, 3) %>% do(data.frame(x=1:2))
# Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
# Groups: replicate

#   replicate x
# 1         1 1
# 2         1 2
# 3         2 1
# 4         2 2
# 5         3 1
# 6         3 2
```