# k-fold cross-validation in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

[Hadley Wickham proposed](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/269) that it could be possible to conduct bootstrap using `dplyr` package, his suggestion [was improved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793383/using-dplyrs-do-to-perform-bootstrap-replications/25794676#25794676) and then [implemented in `broom` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/bootstrapping.html). Would it be also possible to implement k-fold cross-validation?

I guess that the first step (selecting the *train* group) is very simple:

```
crossvalidate <- function (df, k = 5) {
  n <- nrow(df)
  idx <- sample(rep_len(1:k, n))
  attr(df, "indices") <- lapply(1:k, function(i) which(idx != i))
  attr(df, "drop") <- TRUE
  attr(df, "group_sizes") <- nrow(df) - unclass(table(idx))
  attr(df, "biggest_group_size") <- max(attr(df, "group_sizes"))
  attr(df, "labels") <- data.frame(replicate = 1:k)
  attr(df, "vars") <- list(quote(replicate))
  class(df) <- c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  df
}
```

But somehow I cannot find anywhere any documentation of `attr(, "indices")` to learn if it is somehow possible to use indices *"other that"* the ones selected for selecting the *test* group indices. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You should have a look at [`modelr`](https://github.com/hadley/modelr), Hadley's package with a `crossv_kfold` function.

Answer (score 2):

https://rpubs.com/dgrtwo/cv-modelr - there you have an example of k-fold cross-validation using `dplyr` package:

```
library(ISLR)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(modelr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)

models <- Smarket %>%
  select(Today, Lag1:Lag5) %>%
  crossv_kfold(k = 20) %>%
  mutate(model = map(train, ~ lm(Today ~ ., data = .)))

predictions <- models %>%
  unnest(map2(model, test, ~ augment(.x, newdata = .y)))

predictions %>%
  summarize(MSE = mean((Today - .fitted) ^ 2),
            MSEIntercept = mean((Today - mean(Today))^2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution for stratified 5-fold CV using dplyr:

```
df_fold = df %>%
  group_by(group_var) %>%
  sample_frac(1) %>%
  mutate(fold=rep(1:5, length.out=n())) %>%
  ungroup

for(i in 1:5){
  val = df_fold %>% filter(fold==i)
  tr = df_fold %>% anti_join(val, by=ID_var)
}
```